# Image won't fill the div container

Tags: css, image

I have a sidebar with cards I want the images to fill it's container I used

```
object-fit cover and contain
```

the first one will cut part of my image and it won't look nice  object fit contain is resizing my image and it's too small it won't  take the free space in this div

I tried object-fit property with contain and cover values

Comment: If you have a div that doesn't conform to an image's aspect ratio, and you want to have the image edge to edge then try `min-width:100%` and `min-height: 100%`. That'll stretch the image to the edges but it will also distort the image.

Comment: I found where the problem is I was using object fit contain with max-height 140px for the img tag now  it's working fine :D